# Child view of list view

Tags: android, listview, view

I have Custome List view which contains several textview and imageview.I want to get that view.How can i get that.My code is as follows.I want to apply font style all over thae aap.its working fine for all view bt not in adapter of list view.please suggest me.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
private Typeface typeace;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    typeace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), getResources().getString(R.string.font_name_fragment));
    //FlurryAgent.init(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.flurry_key));
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    overrideFonts(getActivity(), view);
}

private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(typeace);

        } else if (v instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) v).setTypeface(typeace);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i want to apply font style in every view of window bt its not working in adapter in list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you have answer suggest here.

Comment: `maybe` can you show your complete classs?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list item in the ListView as follows and add your own typeface to it

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
                txtView.setTypeface(typeace);
            }
});
```

or in the adapter also as

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View view = null;
    if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
        holder.txt.setTypeFace(typeface);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.txt.setText("Text");
    return view;
}
```

Comment: i have to many list views i am unable to fix it on each n evry textview by this

Comment: Try to write a class Fonts which accepts a parameter View, send your TextView to that and set font in the Fonts class